# Java GUI save a pdf (PdfAcroForm) with JFileChooser

Tags: java, user-interface

I did a lot of researches on this site but i didn't find anything connected to my situation, so I'm kindly looking for an advice in order to reach the following result:

I'm working on a Java GUI and I developed an application to create an invoice.
On my project's folder i uploaded a blank pdf (that includes forms named: "nr_invoice", "client", "service", "price", "quantity", "tax" and "tot"), this pdf is named "invoice.pdf". Through the following code, by clicking a button on the GUI, the datas in the GUI are reported into the selected pdf's fields and the pdf is saved into the folder "src/pdf" with the name "new_invoice.pdf".

The code works, but what I'd like to do is to show a save file dialog (using JFileChooser) when the user click on the button "btnSave". So, by clicking on this button, the user is able to choose the save path and also the name of the file (but will be possible to save only a .pdf format).

Thank you very much for your help!

```
public class PdfGenerator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   public static final String SRC = "src/pdf/invoice.pdf";
   public static final String DEST = "src/pdf/new_invoice.pdf";

   PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
                Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
                fields.get("nr_invoice").setValue(invoice.getText());
                fields.get("client").setValue(cl_name.getText());
                fields.get("service").setValue(description.getText());
                fields.get("price").setValue(amount.getText());
                fields.get("quantity").setValue(quantity.getText());
                fields.get("tax").setValue(tax_amount.getText());
                fields.get("tot").setValue(total_price.getText());
                form.flattenFields();
                pdf.close();
            }
        });
```

}

Comment: `src` won't exist when the app is exported and you shouldn't reference it from you code

Comment: [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to follow some tutorial about how to use File Choosers but my problem is in this line of the code:
'PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));'
I don't know how set the file choosers on PdfWriter, instead "DEST".
About the 'src' there is no problems, it's an app I'm developing only to better understand GUI and pdf creation.

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem. The tutorial demonstrates how to get the file name selected by the user. You use that value instead of your hard coded DEST variable. So the point is you need to create the PDF AFTER the file chooser is displayed and the user has choosen the file name.

Comment: @camickr Thank you very much for the explanation. Now I perfectly understand it and the code is working. Thanks again!